# GridView show only single Row in custom adapter?

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to add gridview dynamically with custom adapter but it is showing only sinle row

I have tried WRAP_CONTENT,MATCH_PARENT,FILL_PARENT for height but it is not working for me

if i am passing static height like 1000 then it is showing is there any solution for this

//Grid View Code (mainLayout is my parent layout)

```
mParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,playerSearchLayout.getId());

        grdPlayers=new GridView(getApplicationContext());

         grdPlayers.setLayoutParams(mParams);

         grdPlayers.setNumColumns(5);
         grdPlayers.setColumnWidth(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
         grdPlayers.setVerticalSpacing(5);
         grdPlayers.setHorizontalSpacing(5);

         mainLayout.addView(grdPlayers);
```

//Adapter Coding

```
package customAdapters;

import java.util.List;



import PropertiesClasses.PlayerProperties;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlayerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private List<PlayerProperties> playerData;
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;


    //Layouts

    RelativeLayout outerLayout;
    RelativeLayout playerDetailsLayout;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    ImageView userImage;
    TextView txtVotes;
    RadioButton radioVote;

    public PlayerAdapter(List<PlayerProperties> player,Activity activity,Context context)
    {
        playerData=player;
        this.activity=activity;
        this.context=context;

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return playerData.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        userImage=new ImageView(activity.getApplicationContext());
        userImage.setId(10000+position);
        userImage.setLayoutParams(params);
        userImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.player);

        params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,userImage.getId());
        playerDetailsLayout=new RelativeLayout(activity.getApplicationContext());
        playerDetailsLayout.setId(11000+position);
        playerDetailsLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greybg);
        playerDetailsLayout.setLayoutParams(params);


        params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,playerDetailsLayout.getId());
        radioVote=new RadioButton(activity.getApplicationContext());
        radioVote.setId(17000+position);
        radioVote.setLayoutParams(params);






        outerLayout=new RelativeLayout(activity.getApplicationContext());
        outerLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        //outerLayout.addView(userImage);
        outerLayout.addView(userImage);
        outerLayout.addView(playerDetailsLayout);
        outerLayout.addView(radioVote);

        return outerLayout;

    }





}
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using an XML file and reusing views? The way you're doing things now is very inefficient since you will constantly be creating new views instead of reusing old ones that can be recycled. And everything you're doing in code can be done in XML which is much cleaner and easier to manage

Comment: try this : mainLayout.addView(grdPlayers,mParams);